# GOLANG Результат запуска программы через библиотеку os/exec на Windows отличается от нативного

Tags: windows, golang, backend

Результат запуска программы через библиотеку os/exec на  Windows отличается от нативного - в шестнадцатеричном редакторе видно, что символ ":w" заменяется на "a" по всему файлу:

[image: Скрин сравнения двух бинарных файлов]

Код, запускающий .exe, порождающий вышеуказанный файл:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os/exec"
)

// Конвертирует файл с использованием проприетарного по
func convertFile(dirname string) {
    cmd := exec.Command(dirname + "App.exe")
    cmd.Dir = dirname
    log.Printf("Running command and waiting for it to finish...")
    error := cmd.Run()
    defer cmd.Process.Kill()
    if error != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error launching:", error.Error())
        log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", error)
    }
    log.Printf("Convertation finished")

    return
}
```

Возможно, нужно передать какой-то параметр exec.Command? Типа локали или еще чего-то, что есть при запуске из интерфейса? Приветствуется любая помощь\указание направлений для размышления и экспериментов.

go version go1.12.5 windows/amd64 
Windows 10 1903
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Что значит "нативный"? Вы в консоли запускаете консольное приложение или?

Comment: И что есть скрины? Откуда они получены? В чём отличия?

Comment: @IvanBlack, спасибо за наводку, проверил запуск через powerShell и CMD - ноги растут оттуда,а не из go
по какой-то причине приложение работает по-разному в зависимости от способа запуска

Comment: @hedgehogues процитирую из оригинального сообщения: "в шестнадцатеричном редакторе видно, что символ ":w" заменяется на "a" по всему файлу:"

Comment: Так непонятно, чем отличается файл справа от файла слева

Comment: Так непонятно, чем отличается файл справа от файла слева. Как Вы их получили

Comment: @hedgehogues Слева - сгенерированный по двойному клику, справа - запуском os\exec.

Подсвечено первое вхождение отличающихся символов. 
Названия файлов и прочее опущено намеренно - мне хотелось бы понять, как можно нивелировать разницу в окружениях запуска (на платформе windows), а не получить готовое решение задачи

Comment: Тогда поясните, что есть двойной клик? Простите, я работаю на ubuntu и мне это не ясно

Comment: @hedgehogues chmod +x filename, затем двойной клик по нему - запустить. По двойному клику Вы, например, папки открываете. Довольно стандартная операция в  UI. Для этой задачи нужна Windows из-за используемого проприетарного ПО. 

Совсем подробно: есть исполняемый файл, он считывает текстовый файл с определенным  именем в одной папке с собой, туда же сохраняет результат в другом файле. Исполняемый файл можно запустить из командной строки, можно из интерфейса (двойными кликом или кл. Enter), Файлы получаются разными. Пытаюсь понять, почему.

Comment: Если открываете по ярлыку, то там могут быть аргументы в этом ярлыке. Дело обычное.

Comment: @IvanBlack, нет, открываю запуском самого .exe. Я думаю. что что-то типа кодировки отличается при способе запуска. Пока неясно, ответ напишу сюда

Comment: В общем, проблема выяснилась: При запуске .exe из командной строке полтягивалась системная dll вместо той, что находилась рядом с файлом. Отсюда и различия в символах. Файл, тем не менее, оказалсяс корректным, так что более я ничего не менял. Спасибо всем!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, проблема выяснилась: При запуске .exe из командной строке подтягивалась системная dll вместо той, что находилась рядом с файлом. Отсюда и различия в символах. Файл, тем не менее, оказалсся корректным, так что более я ничего не менял. Обойти это можно было бы с помощь заворачивание вызова .exe в .bat файл. Спасибо всем!